# Perl regex: replacing optional parts of URL

Tags: regex, perl

I have a properties file with HTTP/database URLs such as the following:

```
http://localhost:8888/some_user?holiday=true
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9999/another_user?holiday=true&paid=true
jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/some_user
http://localhost/some_user
```

Each URL appears in a separate line.

Each line can end with white spaces (spaces/tabs), `\n`, or nothing (if it's the last line).

The differences between lines:

- the URL may be a web URL, or some database URL,
- there may or may not be a port number,
- there may or may not be optional parameters,
- the user name

**I want to replace the port number (if exist) and the user name with `XXXX`.**

For example, the previous URLs should become:

```
http://localhost:XXXX/XXXX?holiday=true
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:XXXX/XXXX?holiday=true&paid=true
jdbc:mysql://localhost:XXXX/XXXX
http://localhost/XXXX
```

*Here is what I have done:*

I broke it down to two regular expressions... looks like I will have to if I want to use look arounds:

- Replace port numbers if exist:

  `perl -i -0777 -pe 's/(?<=localhost:)\d+/XXXX/g' file;`
- Then, replace user names:

  `perl -i -0777 -pe 's/(?<=localhost\/)(?<=localhost:XXXX\/)[\S&[^?]]*(?=[?\s\Z]?)/XXXX/g' file;`

The second regex did not replace the user name... any idea what is wrong?

Also, is there a simple way to take into account the case when it's the last line, which may not end in a whitespace such as newline.

Comment: Contrary to your claims, those aren't URLs at all. What are they? We can't expect to parse them if we don't know the format

Comment: @ikegami The database URLs are in JDBC format. I don't know if it is the correct term but usually they are referred to as URLs.

Comment: Where aye docs for "the JBDC format"?

Comment: @ikegami Probably in the JDBC spec, but here is an example https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.2.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.vvm_ag_guide.10.2.0.doc/c_ag_samjdcurlform.html I did not originally think it would make much difference so I left this detail out for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the complexities of URL parsing in general, it is better to use the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/URI-1.72/lib/URI.pm) module.

Here is a two-pass regex. The first regex matches up to the first `/` or `:` (after the protocol identifier), followed by `:` and digits; the `\K` makes it drop all previous matches so only the port is replaced. The second regex replaces all consecutive not-`?` after the first `/`.

```
perl -ple'
    s{^ [^:]* :// [^/:]* : \K \d+ }{XXXX}x;
    s{^ [^:]* :// [^/]* \K [^?]* }{/XXXX}x;
' input > output
```

There is no need to run two one-liners since this goes strictly by-line. Corrected code from [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami).

---

*Update to the question update*

The multiple protocols are correctly processed with the change of regexes' beginning to

```
s{^ .*? ://  ...
```

so to match anything up to, and including, the first `://`.  The rest is the same.

Comment: Yours could accidentally clobber the path or the query (when trying to edit the port). Yours could accidentally clobber the query (when trying to edit the path). Yours could replace only part of the path instead of all of it. Yours could fail to replace the path at all. In other words, you made loads more assumptions than the linked version.

Comment: Examples of mishandled URLs described above: `http://www:5678/foo:1234/`, `http://www/foo?bar=:1234/`, `http://www/foo?bar/baz`, `http://www`, `http://www/foo/bar`

Comment: @ikegami  (I got pulled away.)  Thank you, this cleared it up (I misplaced where the port is :(.  Yes, there were extra assumptions ... will edit now

Comment: @ikegami What do you think is wrong with my change?

Comment: @rapt Note changes. I also suggest a module, but if you need a regex this can be used/adapted. Just keep in mind what it expects and how exactly it works (if modifying).

Answer (score 3):

Why bother with a regex? The URI module can do it all for you:

```
perl -MURI -ple 'my $u = URI->new($_); $u->path("XXXX"); $u->_port("XXXX") if $u->_port; $_ = $u'
```

Comment: @ikegami `port` returns the default port for the scheme if the URI doesn't contain an explicit port. See https://metacpan.org/pod/URI#$uri-%3Eport.

Comment: @melpomene I am getting `Can't locate object method "_port" via package "URI::_generic" at -e line 1, <> line 1.` Also some of my URLs are database URL such as `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/mydb`, is it still supposed to work?

Comment: @rapt No, but your question was about HTTP URLs.

Comment: @melpomene I thought to handle it with regex. Let me update my question.